# jquery html table in variable row count

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea how to count rows from a table generated by $.post . I was able to get the html code to a global variable but no success to use it as a input for row count function.

```
var prelaz;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    var brkart = $("#brk").val();
    var ime = $("#im").val();
    var prez = $("#pre").val();
    var adres = $("#adr").val();
    var tele = $("#tel").val();

    $.post("getpacijent.php", {
      b: brkart, 
      i: ime, 
      p: prez, 
      a: adres,
      t: tele
    }, function(data) { 
      $("#izlaztablica").html(data); 
      prelaz = data; 
    });
  });
});

function PromenaTable() {
  x = (prelaz).attr('rows').length;
  document.getElementById("rowcount").innerHTML= x;
}
```

I call function `PromenaTabele()` when any of fields `#brk`, `#im`, `#pre`, `#adr`, `#tel` changes.

Comment: Your prelaz=data belongs to another scope, therefore, you cant access it within PromenaTable(). Other thing is that defining prelaz globally is not good idea. And third, your table is created so is there when you call PromenTable, right? If you dont have table head and table body you might just do this: var rowCount = $('#yourTable tr').length; But if you have it, then do somehting like this: var rowCount = $('#yourTable >tbody >tr').length;
Hope this helps, if does, let me know :) i will create answer

Comment: prelaz is global and I can access it from `function PromenaTabele()`. I've tried to print only prelaz as a variable and I get table on event in div I've created for debuging only. Also Table is created on event keyup and PromenaTabele is triggered with onchange witch is after input whitch I need. I want to enable, with this procedure, a submit button when number of rows is 1. Problem is that I need to use data from ajax/jquery call witch is not rendered in HTML page and I can not use id to get table. Can I use javascript variable to point a HTML rather then #id.

Comment: Not sure i understand. Here:  prelaz = data;  You are assigning json to var prelaz. I suppose that getPcijent.php return jSon? Did you tried to log prelaz in PromenaTable()? console.log(prelaz) What is outpuit?

Comment: no getpacijent.php return plain html table witch is generated from a tabase search. error is "undefined" but I think that problem is I use variable as an id in function and function expect id not variable...

Comment: ping me na skajp - vladimir_nikolic

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
    function PromenaTable() {
       var table=$("#tableId").find('tr').length;  // Count Number Of Rows
       var table=$("#tableId").find('tr').not(':first').length;//Count Number of Rows Excluding the 1st Row i.e Table Headings 

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use id as a pointer to table but variable content?

Comment: You can access it with element name , class and Id selector